# Use selectize.js to populate a second dropdown

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I have two dropdowns, that the choice of the first dropdown , populates properly the second one.I have successfully implemented it using ajax-php.

Now i am trying to use [selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) ,applied to the first of the `select` (the first dropdown) which works fine as expected, but the second dropdown is not populated properly. I have read the documentation (which is not the best i have ever read), and i think that by default selectize.js is not able to handle metadata.

However there is an `addOption()` and an `addItem()` method which is what i should implement.My problem is that i can't find a way to parse the results given by ajax-php(and get stored as `options` in the second dropdown ) and use them properly...

**PHP Code**

```
echo "<select name='universities' id='universities' ></select>"; //Here is where the second dropdown is populated properly
```

**JQuery Code-update second dropdown**

```
//Successfully the second dropdown is populated before     
$("#universities").selectize();
//If i change the first dropdown option now,the second dropdown remains the same
//if i comment  $("#universities").selectize(); line everything works fine.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this example with update your query

**HTML**

```
// first drop down menu
<select id="city" name="city">
    <option value="">Select City</option>
    <option value="1">Cairo</option>
    <option value="2">Alexandria</option>
    <option value="3">Tanta</option>
</select>

// Second drop down menu you want to populate it depending on the choosing from first drop down menu
<select id="universities" name="universities"></select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $("#city").change(function() {
        var city_id = $(this).val();
        var selectize = $("#universities")[0].selectize;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/gitUniversities.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                city_id: city_id,
            },
            error: function(response) {
                selectize.clear();
                selectize.clearOptions();
                selectize.disable();
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                //alert(response);
                selectize.enable();
                selectize.clear();
                selectize.clearOptions();
                selectize.load(function(callback) {
                    callback(response.data);
                });
            }
        });
    });

    $('#universities').selectize({
        valueField: 'key',
        labelField: 'value',
        searchField: 'value',
        options: [],
        create: false,
        render: {
            option: function(data, escape) {
                return '<div class="option">' + escape(data.value) +'</div>';
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

**PHP**

gitUniversities.php file

```
// city_id came from ajax request
$city_id = $_GET['city_id'];
// your query to select from table `universities`  where the city = city_id
$universities = SELECT `id` as 'key',`name` as 'value' FROM `universities` WHERE `city_id` = $city_id;
// return data as json
return json_encode(['data' => $universities, 'status' => true]);
```

It suppose to work with you now

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the sample here: http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/

Look at the City/State example. Key is the **.load** method. From inside the **states dropdown** the onChange event has an ajax call that loads the city drop down. The onChange event of the states dropdown is called and the selected value is passed into the function and sent to the url to get the universities. The callback function returns the results that you want loaded into the city dropdown.

```
   onChange: function(value) {
            if (!value.length) return;
            select_city.disable();
            select_city.clearOptions();
            select_city.load(function(callback) {
                xhr && xhr.abort();
                xhr = $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://jsonp.afeld.me/?url=http://api.sba.gov/geodata/primary_city_links_for_state_of/' + value + '.json',
                    success: function(results) {
                        select_city.enable();
                        callback(results); <--- THIS CALL RETURNS THE JSON RESULTS TO THE CALLER
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        callback(); <--THIS RETURNS TO CALLER ON ERROR 
                    }
                })
            });
```

Comment: There is a note in the documentation saying 'API is spotty. If city fails to load it is a problem'. Cities are not loading. What might be a problem?

Comment: There's no point just repeating what the selectize documentation(for what it is). It's far more helpful if you can give concrete example that is different or extends the documentation.